# Warning: React does not recognize the `textColor` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Getting this warning: `Warning: React does not recognize the 'textColor' prop on a DOM element` (everything else is working).

Using it in my component this way:

```
import { ImageWithFallback, Paper, Tabs, Tab, Typography, Tooltip,} from '@material-ui-core/dist';

<Paper square className={classes.root} data-test-id={testMediaEditRenditionTabPanel.paper}>
      <Tabs
        value={tabState}
        variant="scrollable"
        onChange={handleChange}
        orientation="vertical"
        indicatorColor="primary"
        centered
        textColor="primary"
        className={classes.tabs}
      >
      </Tabs>
</Paper>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of MUI are you using?

Comment: @NearHuscarl, it is 4.8.2

Comment: the same error shows when useing "textColor" in MUI chips

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `textcolor` instead of `textColor`? I think the material UI of your project seems not to be the latest version. Please let me know how it works.

Comment: Yes I did @Maxim but it throw following error.


No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & { action?: ((instance: TabsActions | null) => void) | RefObject<TabsActions> | null | undefined; ... 11 more ...; width?: string | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.


yes material-ui version is 4.8.2.

Comment: Hmm. Got it. Could you show me your `package.json`? @sameer-huilgolkar